# MySQL equivalent of Oracle's SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, spring

I need to be able to generate run a query that will return the next value of ID on the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

In Oracle you can call NEXTVAL on a sequence and it gives you the next sequence (note: without having to do an insert on the table).

After googling around I found that you can find the current value of auto_increment by using the following query:

```
SELECT Auto_increment 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_name='animals';
```

The problem is I would like the value to be increment every time the value is queried. In Oracle, when you call nextval, the value of the sequence is incremented even if you don't insert a row into a table.

Is there any way I can modify the above query so that the value returned will always be different from the last time the query was called? i.e. Auto_increment is incremented every time it is checked and when used on a query it would use a new value.

I am using Spring JDBCTemplate so if it can be done in one query the better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This example with InnoDB demonstrates a way to implement your own counter using interlocked queries:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

What do you need to create a gap for? To reserve IDs?
I'd rather "fix" the design at all costs and update the other modules instead of touching a sequence.

Instead of just incrementing the sequence explicitly, I'd imply it by inserting a default row (marked invalid) for each id to allocate and return the id. This approach is consistent and portable.
Later, instead of forcing inserts using an explicit sequence value, you can update these default rows by their matching sequence values.
This requires more memory but no locks. Garbage collection on expired rows can help here. 'insert or update' statements can recreate garbage collected rows, I wouldn't do this though.

Comment: At all costs? Really?

Answer (score 15):

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/example-auto-increment.html

**3.6.9. Using AUTO_INCREMENT**

The AUTO_INCREMENT attribute can be used to generate a unique identity for new rows:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE animals (
>      id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>      name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
>      PRIMARY KEY (id)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO animals (name) VALUES
>     ('dog'),('cat'),('penguin'),
>     ('lax'),('whale'),('ostrich');
>
> SELECT * FROM animals;
> Which returns:
>
> +----+---------+
> | id | name    |
> +----+---------+
> |  1 | dog     |
> |  2 | cat     |
> |  3 | penguin |
> |  4 | lax     |
> |  5 | whale   |
> |  6 | ostrich |
> +----+---------+
> ```

No value was specified for the AUTO_INCREMENT column, so MySQL assigned sequence numbers automatically. You can also explicitly assign NULL or 0 to the column to generate sequence numbers.

You can retrieve the most recent AUTO_INCREMENT value with the LAST_INSERT_ID() SQL function or the mysql_insert_id() C API function. These functions are connection-specific, so their return values are not affected by another connection which is also performing inserts.

Use the smallest integer data type for the AUTO_INCREMENT column that is large enough to hold the maximum sequence value you will need. When the column reaches the upper limit of the data type, the next attempt to generate a sequence number fails. Use the UNSIGNED attribute if possible to allow a greater range. For example, if you use TINYINT, the maximum permissible sequence number is 127. For TINYINT UNSIGNED, the maximum is 255. See Section 11.2.1, “Integer Types (Exact Value) - INTEGER, INT, SMALLINT, TINYINT, MEDIUMINT, BIGINT” for the ranges of all the integer types.

Note
For a multiple-row insert, LAST_INSERT_ID() and mysql_insert_id() actually return the AUTO_INCREMENT key from the first of the inserted rows. This enables multiple-row inserts to be reproduced correctly on other servers in a replication setup.

If the AUTO_INCREMENT column is part of multiple indexes, MySQL generates sequence values using the index that begins with the AUTO_INCREMENT column, if there is one. For example, if the animals table contained indexes PRIMARY KEY (grp, id) and INDEX (id), MySQL would ignore the PRIMARY KEY for generating sequence values. As a result, the table would contain a single sequence, not a sequence per grp value.

To start with an AUTO_INCREMENT value other than 1, set that value with CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE, like this:

mysql> ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
InnoDB Notes

For InnoDB tables, be careful if you modify the column containing the auto-increment value in the middle of a sequence of INSERT statements. For example, if you use an UPDATE statement to put a new, larger value in the auto-increment column, a subsequent INSERT could encounter a “Duplicate entry” error. The test whether an auto-increment value is already present occurs if you do a DELETE followed by more INSERT statements, or when you COMMIT the transaction, but not after an UPDATE statement.

MyISAM Notes

For MyISAM tables, you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a secondary column in a multiple-column index. In this case, the generated value for the AUTO_INCREMENT column is calculated as MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE prefix=given-prefix. This is useful when you want to put data into ordered groups.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE animals (
>     grp ENUM('fish','mammal','bird') NOT NULL,
>     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (grp,id)
> ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
>
> INSERT INTO animals (grp,name) VALUES
>     ('mammal','dog'),('mammal','cat'),
>     ('bird','penguin'),('fish','lax'),('mammal','whale'),
>     ('bird','ostrich');
>
> SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY grp,id;
> Which returns:
>
> +--------+----+---------+
> | grp    | id | name    |
> +--------+----+---------+
> | fish   |  1 | lax     |
> | mammal |  1 | dog     |
> | mammal |  2 | cat     |
> | mammal |  3 | whale   |
> | bird   |  1 | penguin |
> | bird   |  2 | ostrich |
> +--------+----+---------+
> ```

In this case (when the AUTO_INCREMENT column is part of a multiple-column index), AUTO_INCREMENT values are reused if you delete the row with the biggest AUTO_INCREMENT value in any group. This happens even for MyISAM tables, for which AUTO_INCREMENT values normally are not reused.

Further Reading

More information about AUTO_INCREMENT is available here:

How to assign the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute to a column: Section 13.1.17, “CREATE TABLE Syntax”, and Section 13.1.7, “ALTER TABLE Syntax”.

How AUTO_INCREMENT behaves depending on the NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO SQL mode: Section 5.1.7, “Server SQL Modes”.

How to use the LAST_INSERT_ID() function to find the row that contains the most recent AUTO_INCREMENT value: Section 12.14, “Information Functions”.

Setting the AUTO_INCREMENT value to be used: Section 5.1.4, “Server System Variables”.

AUTO_INCREMENT and replication: Section 16.4.1.1, “Replication and AUTO_INCREMENT”.

Server-system variables related to AUTO_INCREMENT (auto_increment_increment and auto_increment_offset) that can be used for replication: Section 5.1.4, “Server System Variables”.

http://search.oracle.com/search/search?q=auto_increment&group=Documentation&x=0&y=0

Answer (score 5):

You could add your own MySQL function - as demonstrated at http://www.microshell.com/database/mysql/emulating-nextval-function-to-get-sequence-in-mysql/ - allowing you to do something like this:

```
SELECT nextval('sq_my_sequence') as next_sequence;
```

Comment: I saw that example while googling. Unfortunately it requires removal of the use of AUTO_INCREMENT on the ID column which is not possible at the moment as i will need to change other modules that use this table - Thanks.

Comment: In the comments on that page there someone raises the concern that there might be a race condition. It seems easier to use the auto_increment method @Ivan gave, where the work is done in a single statement, and is therefore atomic. You could wrap Ivan's method in a function, which would be nice though, giving you the best of both approaches.

Comment: can you update your answer for the actual content instead of link? the query you provide alone will not work.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL uses `AUTO_INCREMENT` which serves the purposes. But there are below differences:

MySQL `AUTO_INCREMENT` to Oracle `SEQUENCE` Differences

- AUTO_INCREMENT is limited to one column per table
- AUTO_INCREMENT must be assigned to a specific table.column (not allowing multi table use)
- AUTO_INCREMENT is INSERTed as a not specified column, or a value of NULL

if you would like to see a SEQUENCE implementation with MySQL , can do with SP.

Refer below link explained everything you want.

http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/sequences-in-mysql-2006-01-26/

Answer (score 1):

You want the next value on THAT table so that you can make rows which aren't yet inserted without disturbing other processes which are using the auto-increment?

Some options:

Go ahead and just insert the rows to "use up the sequence", mark them as pending and then update them later.

Insert in a transaction and abort the transaction - the auto-number sequence should get used up and make a "gap" in the table normally - that number is now free for you to use.

With Oracle, the sequence is completely independent of table, so processes can use the sequence or not (and they can also use the same sequence for different tables).  In that vein, you could implement a sequence-only table which you access through some kind of function, and for the other processes which need to rely on the auto-increment, remove the auto-increment and use a trigger which assigns from the same sequence function if no id is provided.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at MariaDBs `SEQUENCE` Engine. With it you can generate sequences as easy as

```
SELECT seq FROM seq_1_to_5;
+-----+
| seq |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   2 |
|   3 |
|   4 |
|   5 |
+-----+
```

Details [here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sequence/](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sequence/)

With this you should be able to do something like

```
SELECT min(seq) as nextVal FROM seq_1_to_500 
WHERE seq NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM customers)
```

Comment: Interesting thing, but most probably not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.) create table query
2.) Insert query
3.) Update query
4.) Select query for that table e.g. SELECT next_val FROM hib_sequence;
5.) Before each select update first, like this you can achieve similar

-- CREATE TABLE hib_sequence (next_val INT NOT NULL);
-- UPDATE hib_sequence SET next_val=LAST_INSERT_ID(next_val+1);
-- select last_insert_id();
-- INSERT INTO hib_sequence VALUES (0);

-- select next_val from hib_sequence;
```