# CREATE SEQUENCE IN MYSQL

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have a PL/SQL Sequence in oracle . I use oracle DB and php The code is as follows-

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_ID
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
MAXVALUE 99999999
MINVALUE 1
NOCYCLE;
```

insert values in column like this

```
UPDATE tableName SET columnName = seq_test_id.NEXTVAL
```

How can i implement it in php oci_parse

Comment: Your subject shouts "MySQL", yet you claim to be using Oracle. What exactly is it. (And sequences in Oracle have nothing to do with PL/SQL)

Comment: What the horse above me said, but also: if your question is "what is sequence in mysql", and also if i'm not mistaken: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: sinc ehe mentioned `oci_parse` id assume its Oracle that actually applies...

Comment: @prodigitalson: I assume this as well, but still maybe the OP means something completely different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL equivalent of Oracle's SEQUENCE.NEXVAL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046971/mysql-equivalent-of-oracles-sequence-nexval)

Comment: Actually i want to implement it in php using oracle DB. I need to update a column. What code should i need to write exactly?

Comment: So you are **not** using MySQL?

Comment: No man.I am using oracle database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're going to Oracle, just set up the statement, parse, and execute. There's no need to do any binding because you have no bind variables. This is adapted from the [PHP documentation of oci_parse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-parse.php):

```
$conn = oci_connect(your username, your password, your database);
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'UPDATE tableName SET columnName = seq_test_id.NEXTVAL');
oci_execute($stid);
```

Comment: Sorry, first post of the answer had the doc page's SQL. It's been updated with the OP's SQL.

Comment: should i save the seq_test_id sequence in the oracle DB?

Comment: When you do `CREATE SEQUENCE seq_test_id...` you *are* saving it in the DB.