# How to Insert in the 3 or More Tables, When Each Table is Relative to previous Table

Tags: mysql, transactions, commit

i have 3 tables that i want insert in these with single query. These tables have more columns, but here I explain them very simple.
i need a single query that insert this records in those tables.

the first table is entities

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC |

the second table is entities_pattern

| id | entID | patID (id of pattern table) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 1 | 101 |

and the third table is stock_room

| id | entPatID | inventory |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |

if we ignore the third table, we can use this query.

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO
    `entities` (`name`)
    VALUES ('ABC');
SET @rowCount = ROW_COUNT();
SET @lastID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO
    `entities_pattern` (`entID`, `patID`)
    VALUES
        (@lastID, '100'),
        (@lastID, '101');
COMMIT;
```

but I don't know how to add the third table to this query.
it may be possible to use this query.

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO
    `entities` (`name`)
    VALUES ('ABC');
SET @rowCount = ROW_COUNT();
SET @lastID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO
    `entities_pattern` (`entID`, `patID`)
    VALUES
        (@lastID, '100'),
        (@lastID, '101');
SET @rowCount = ROW_COUNT();
SET @lastID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO
    `stock_room` (`entPatID` , `inventory`)
    VALUES
        (@lastID, '0'),
        (@lastID+1, '0');
COMMIT;
```

i have 2 questions now:

1- is this query the best way to do it?

2- what will happen if multiple users want to enter something in these tables at the same time? Can we be sure that @lastID +1, gives us the true entPatID?

Comment: OK, so don't try to guess the id's of the records you inserted to the entities_pattern table.  You need to get the actual id's.  One way to do that is to query the entities_pattern table using the last_id and get the id's of those new rows.

Comment: Thanks, but my emphasis in this question is to insert all three records with single query and I don't want it to be done in two steps.

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895597/insert-multiple-rows-parent-lastinsertid)

Comment: in this question we have 3 table, for 2 table i write the solotion in my question