# how to add an ID with both string and auto incremented number in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, auto-increment

I'm working on a database project, and I'm stuck here with its ID. Basically, the ID consists of a type and a number, when we insert new data into the table, it should automatically assign a new ID to the data, such as MS-1, MS-2, MS-3, DS-1,DS-2,PC-2,PC-3, I know how to concatenate a string with auto increment number in sql, while I'm not really sure how to deal with this issue with different strings. Thanks in advance for any helpful suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exactly my case was, and I have solved, see my answer there in [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50831922/oracle-sequences-equivalent-in-mysql) question.

Let me try to answer it systematically as well.

```
create table my_seq(
min_value integer,
Max_value integer,
last_value integer,
increment_by tinyint,
type varchar)ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Then create data values like,

```
insert into my_seq(min_value,max_value,last_value,increment_by,type) 
  values(1,99999999,1,1,'foo#','DS'),(1,999999999,1,1,'foo#','MS'),(1,999999999,1,1,'foo#','DOC');
```

Make sure you have `auto-commit=false`.
Then, do it like this in your app, or database code,

```
//very import to begin the transaction
begin;
select CONCAT(type_val,'-',last_value) from my_seq where type_val=? FOR UPDATE;

Read the result in App or database procedure/trigger

update my_seq set last_number=last_number+1 where type_val=?;
commit;
```

Make sure there is `index` on `type_val`.

I believe this should work.

Comment: thanks so much for your quick response and this helps a lot!

Comment: @binwei good to know it helped you. Would you mind accepting it as correct answer then?